# WebUtils.ApiCall returns no error message after Post

Tags: c#, api, http-post

I'm trying to use Core.WebUtils.ApiCall to get informations from an API. Basically trying to create a shipment on DHL's API. (I have a test key for it)
The biggest problem for me is that the error message shows nothing that can help. There is no "message" beside the line where the error happened. I have no clue as to what happens.

Here's the piece of code:

```
public static DHLShipmentResponse CreateAPIDHLShipment(DhlapiCall shipment, string apiKey)
        {
            string url = "https://api-gw.dhlparcel.nl/";
            string urlParameters = "shipments";

            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(apiKey + ":");
            var auth = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

            var postcontent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(shipment);
            var test = ApiCall.RunAsync<DHLShipmentResponse>(url, urlParameters, auth, postcontent);
            var response = ApiCall.RunAsync<DHLShipmentResponse>(url, urlParameters, auth, postcontent).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            return response;
        }
```

Pretty small, pretty basic, witha  few test to see if I could find anything, but to no avail.
Just for good measure, I took the value of "PostContent" to run it through postman and gets no issue. So I'm certain that the content is correct. I double checked the url and again, everything is fine. And as far as I could find, we've always been using authentication that way (bearer tokens).

Here's what I get through Postman:

```
{
    "shipmentId": "69028c6a-ce50-4f2e-9483-27fd0a8f72ec",
    "product": "EPL-INT",
    "pieces": [
        {
            "labelId": "69028c6a-ce50-4f2e-9483-27fd0a8f72ec",
            "trackerCode": "SAMPLE0000180041",
            "parcelType": "PALLET",
            "pieceNumber": 1,
            "weight": 0,
            "labelType": "B2X_Generic_A4_Third"
        }
    ],
    "customsDeclarationId": "9a316738-3ef3-4471-9bd8-7c92deb50338"
}
```

And here's the definition of the response:

```
public partial class DHLShipmentResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("shipmentId")]
    public Guid ShipmentId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("product")]
    public string Product { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("shipmentTrackerCode")]
    public string ShipmentTrackerCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pieces")]
    public List<PieceResponse> Pieces { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("returnShipment")]
    public ReturnShipmentResponse ReturnShipment { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("customsDeclarationId")]
    public string CustomsDeclarationId { get; set; }
}
public partial class PieceResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("labelId")]
    public Guid LabelId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("trackerCode")]
    public string TrackerCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("printlessCode")]
    public string PrintlessCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("parcelType")]
    public string ParcelType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pieceNumber")]
    public long PieceNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("weight")]
    public long Weight { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dimensions")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
    public long Dimensions { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("labelType")]
    public string LabeType { get; set; }
}
```

I've been on it for hours to no avail. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. It was the authentication. It's not a basic token, it's a bearer token. And I don't need to turn it into a byte array before sending it.

Also I learned that core.webutils is NOT a nugget package but one of our library (I could have sworn it wasn't)

Sorry for the time loss, have a nice day